# Align center menu with its content

Tags: html, css, menu, alignment, text-alignment

I'm trying center horizontal the text within a `div` on a menu, with the box size.

Something like this:

[Link to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZMeI.jpg)

My problem is when I try to place the `position: absolute` submenu, the main text does not respect the size and positions of the submenu to the left.

Here is the code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pisagatos/U3sEL/6/).

```
<div id="menu">
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Nosotros</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td> 
             <a>La empresa</a>
             <a>Homologaciones</a>
             <a>Contacto</a>
           </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Servicios</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
              <a>Especialidades</a>
              <a>Vigilancia de la salud</a>
              <a>Formación</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div>Content div</div>
```

The CSS is on the fiddle.

How could I center the main menu with its submenu respecting the box size?

In the example, I made it with `table`, but my idea is make this with `ul` and `li` or `divs`.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you said you were thinking about using ul/li elements instead of table, I think this is a good idea, especially for navigation type structures. Semantically that's what a nav menu is, a *list* of links.

Here's some code that has centered menu/submenu text, that also keeps the width of the hidden submenu items. It's not pretty, you'll have to tweak the css to make it look pretty perfect!

Let me know if that content div isn't positioned right, I could probably work up a solution. ;)

HTML:

```
<div id="menu_wrapper">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>Nosotros
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a>La empresa</a></li>
                    <li><a>Homologaciones</a></li>
                    <li><a>Contacto</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </li>

            <li>Servicios
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a>Especialidades</a></li>
                    <li><a>Vigilancia de la salud</a></li>
                    <li><a>Formación</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
<div>Content div</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul
{
    list-style-type:none;    
}

li
{
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}

.submenu
{
    padding:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    height:0;
}

#menu > li
{
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
}

#menu > li:hover .submenu
{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3sEL/7/

Comment: I apologize Ernesto, I made an edit that should work.

Comment: My problem is other, the divs with "position:absolute;" is overlap